# Как посчитать количество объектов (файлов и папок) в папке?

Tags: python, pathlib

Имееется ввиду использование класса `Path()`, но не обязательно.
Вот такое решение мне кажется громоздким.  Нет ли чего-то изящнее?
Задача решалась 100500 раз, видно плохо гуглил.

```
from pathlib import Path

folder_name = input("folder name:")
folder = Path(folder_name)
if folder.is_dir():
    folder_count = len([1 for file in folder.iterdir()])

print(f"В папке {folder_name} есть {folder_count} объектов")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

количество файлов и поддиректорий в директории:

```
if not folder.is_dir():
    raise ValueError(f"[{folder}] не существует или не является директорией")

print(f"В папке {folder_name} есть {sum(1 for x in folder.iterdir())} объектов")
```

или более понятный вариант:

```
print(f"В папке {folder_name} есть {len(list(folder.iterdir()))} объектов")
```

если нужно рекурсивно посчитать число объектов во всех поддиректориях:

```
len(list(folder.rglob("*")))
```

Comment: ну len()  hf,jnftn работает побыстрее, чем sum(). А за однострочник спасибо.

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, не уверен, что `len()` работает быстрее - надо сравнивать ;)

Comment: Насколько мне помнится,  в списках __len__()  хранится в отжедьном поле, чтоб не считать

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, это так, но список сначала надо получить - материализовать, а `sum()` - умеет работать с генераторами, поэтому я и сказал, что лучше сравнить оба варианта на директории с большим количеством объектов ;)